# Print item of list and another item of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have two lists:

```
list1=[1, 2, 2, 12, 23]
list2=[2, 3, 5, 3, 4]
```

I want to arrange them side by side list1 and list2 using python
so:

```
| list1 | list2 |
|---|---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 23 | 4 |
```

but I want to remove the third row `(2,5)` and make it:

```
| list1 | list2 |
|---|---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3,5 |
| 12 | 3 |
| 23 | 4 |
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Comment: you want the five but u want to remove the third row i dont get it...

Comment: @PratyushArora, it looks they were grouped based on the value from `list1` - both 3 and 5 will be paired with value 2 from `list1`.

Comment: basically its a stem and leaf plot, i dont want duplicate values in list 1,

Comment: make each unique element of list 1 a dict key with empty list as value. Loop over list 2 and add the element to the corresponding key list. Finally iterate over all dict keys and print(key, value). Now look a tutorial on how do do each of the steps and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SembeiNorimaki.i will try that way

Comment: @PtitXav res="\n".join("{} {}".format(a, b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

list1=[1, 2, 2, 12, 23]
list2=[2, 3, 5, 3, 4]

for key, value in groupby(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(f"{key} {','.join(str(y) for x, y in value)}")
```

or if you prefer using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1=[1,2,2,12,23]
list2=[2, 3, 5, 3, 4]

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    result[key].append(value)

for key, value in result.items():
    print(f"{key} {','.join(map(str, value))}")
```

using only loops and built-in functions:

```
list1=[1,2,2,12,23]
list2=[2, 3, 5, 3, 4]

result={}
for key, value in zip(list1, list2):
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

for key, value in result.items():
    print(f"{key} {','.join(map(str, value))}")
```

In all three cases the output is

```
1 2
2 3,5
12 3
23 4
```

Comment: Second one is better,since i am new to python. Thank @buran . I will look into it.
i am not familiar with packages yet. i was hoping to get answer using loops only

Comment: There are no third-party packages in both solutions, only standard python library modules.

Comment: yes the libraries

Comment: OK, I update my answer with only loops and built-in functions. But they are presented in order I would prefer them.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the two lists together and append them to a dictionary. If one value of list 1 already exists as a key in the dictionary, you format the value as a string and append the next one to the same key. I just posted this since it might be easier to follow, however i really like the answer above from @buran.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 12, 23]
list2 = [2, 3, 5, 3, 4]
combo_dict = {}

# zip both lists together and iterate over them
for key, val in zip(list1, list2):
    """if an item in list1 already exists in combo_dict, 
       format the respective overlapping value in list2 as a 
       string and append to the same key to the dict"""
    if key in combo_dict.keys():
        combo_dict[key] = ",".join([f"{combo_dict[key]}", f"{val}"])
    """if not, simply append the value of list 2 with the key of 
       list 1 to the dict (could also format this to a string)"""
    else:
        combo_dict[key] = val

# this is just for printing the dict to the console
no_out=[print(f"{key} {val}") for key, val in combo_dict.items()]
```